# Delete unrecognized afps local snapshots

Tags: time-machine, bootcamp, apfs

When using `diskutil list` in Recovery, I can see 20 disk images that are certainly localsnapshots from Time Machine.

I need to remove these disks so I can use Bootcamp Assistant.

I have disabled Time Machine and removed the associated drives in System Preferences. I have also used `tmutil` (in normal boot) to list and thin any snapshots, but none are reported affected. Meanwhile, the disks are still visible through terminal in Recovery; but not regular boot.

If `tmutil` Is not seeing them, is it safe to delete them via terminal in Recovery?

Thanks for any help!

edit: this is my output when listing disks in recovery
[image]

Comment: localsnapshots don't normally create/live on separate volumes or disk images. Can you provide a listing of exactly what you're seeing?

Comment: See my first edit

Comment: I'm not convinced that these are localsnapshots. I currently have 20 snapshots, but no extra disk images as in your list. Do you see these listed when NOT in Recovery?

Comment: Nope, I discovered that they’re part of recovery and each contain an app or tool. When I started manually ejecting them I lost recovery functionality but by bit.

Comment: Recovery is just one partition with some software that boots up. In your listing, it's disk3 partition 3. There's no reason why you should acquire loads of extra volumes just because you're booting to Recovery. I think the use of 'disk image' is significant: this may mean it's a virtual disk of some kind. If it's not actually a problem when not in Recovery, I wouldn't worry about it.